# Need help with .htaccess, doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently i have url parameters like this `http://www.website.com/index.php?user&page=edit`

And in index.php i have set if `$_GET['user']` is set display user's page and inside user's page i have done something like if `$_GET['page']` is set then find the page (in this case edit) and load that page.

It works well.,

But what changes do i need to make in htaccess file such that the url's become like this `http://www.website.com/user/ - to load user file` and `http://www.website.com/user/edit - to load user edit file`

Here's my htaccess file content

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?$1

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?$1&page=$2
```

But this doesn't seem to work the way i expected.

If i load `http://www.website.com/user/edit - it works` but if i just load `/user/ - it doesn't`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching both rules and adding the `L`-flag:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

`.*` matches every character sequence. That means that `user/edit/` is matched as well as `user/`. You need to place the more specific rule first, to make sure that there is a `/` in between. I suggest that you change that rules to something like this, since the other rules might match stuff that you did not intend:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ index.php?$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

`[^/]+` will match every sequence that does not contain any `/`.

Comment: Great, It works, can i got about adding any number of rules like these? or is there a better solution.

Comment: @Roccos: You should be able to add as many rules as you want, as long as they are unambigious.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is already answered - but your rule could be improved.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/$ index.php?$1
// ...
```

So it doesn't match `/` (slashes) and you don't run into that troubles ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)([^\/.]+)/?$ index.php?$1

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?$1&page=$2

Answer (score 0):

Since `.*` matches *anything* your first rule will always be applied.

You should use a more specific pattern like `[^/]+` (anything but `/`) instead of `.*`:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php?$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ index.php?$1&page=$2
```

Now the first rule will only be applied on paths with just one segment and the second on paths with twi segments.